# QuantLib-Python Libor Market Model

Tags: quantlib

It appears that QuantLib-Python does not include Libor Market Model, although the C++ version has it.

(https://rkapl123.github.io/QLAnnotatedSource/d5/d8d/class_quant_lib_1_1_market_model.html)

Is this understanding correct?

Is there a way to work around? Thanks,

Huarong